# Loading a DataTable with a XML string

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have the `XMLDocument` and I extract the following xml tags I want using the `xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("./tag")` into a string and I want to load it inside a DataTable.

I tried using the `dataTable.ReadXML();` but the overloads for this function do not allow a string argument.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Edit : Adding Code

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(string_With_Xml);
DataTable accessTable = new DataTable();
accessTable.ReadXml();
```

I Hope this adds more context to the question.

Comment: Please show an XML itself and DataTable structure you would like to have, btw LINQ-to-XML much more easier way to do this rather than old style XmlDocument

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/67dacbbf-6358-4de7-b398-293e89cab6b1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
//Your xml
string TestSTring = @"<Contacts> 
                    <Node>
                        <ID>123</ID>
                        <Name>ABC</Name>
                    </Node>
                    <Node>
                        <ID>124</ID>
                        <Name>DEF</Name>
                    </Node>
            </Contacts>";
StringReader StringStream = new StringReader(TestSTring);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(StringStream);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: My only problem with this is that if there are no data values in the XML I still want the DataTable to have the column names from the Xml even though there are no rows available is there a way of doing this?

Comment: @SpaceApple, if you delete the data, for example `ABC`, `123`, and others, you will still get a datatable with columns but no rows.

Comment: I get a XmlException saying "Root Element Missing" when I try and read the xml straight into a DataTable instead of the DataSet.

Comment: @SpaceApple, that is why you should use DataSet

Comment: Now if there is no row data the xml returns <DataSet /> as an empty tag, which I do not want, I want it to return the columns even though there is no datarow. Thats why it breaks when loading in the datatable instead of the dataset. I don't know how to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

you can write extension like this:

```
public static someType ReadXml(this DataTable dt, string yourParam1, string yourParam2)
{
   method body....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following approach, the byte array here can be loaded for a string using for example:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(somestring)
```

Helper method to load the datatable, note fallback to DataSet's method ReadXml instead of Datatable ReadXml. This will not always be suitable in case your xml contains somehow several data tables, as this method always returns the first data table in the catch:

```
   public DataTable Convert(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var text = bytes.ToStringUtf8();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            return null;
        }
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            try
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.ReadXml(stream);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ie)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ie);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                stream.Position = 0;
                ds.ReadXml(stream);
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    return ds.Tables[0];
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```